# Filter out URL in a servlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a service servlet and everything is defined under `app/services/*`, I want to change my controller URL mapping so instead of it being app/services/page, it will be `app/page`. Is there a way to do this in my `web.xml`?

in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>page</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:springConfig/page-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>page</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/page</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

page-servlet.xml:

```
<import resource="page-controller.xml"/>
```

page-controller.xml:

```
<bean id="pageController" class="com.ck.web.controller.pageController"/>
```

When I run it is saying it can't find it, no resource available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `@Controller` annotated class instance is registered to a `DispatcherServlet` which is mapped to a URL based on the definition in the `web.xml`. The `@RequestMapping` path is relative to that path. You cannot keep the URL in `web.xml` but change the `@RequestMapping` path.

What you could do is have two `DispatcherServlet` instances with their own URL mapping and their own `@Controller` instances registered.

Comment: It is still not working, I have added a portion of my web.xml and two other related xml config files.

Comment: @invictvs Is the class name correct, lowercase `p`? Post the exact error message.

Comment: Oh sorry, it should be `PageController`.

Comment: And the error is just a resource not available issue, so there is a mapping issue. It was giving me a Servlet.init() exception but I fixed that.